# Can we create System.xml fileds inside any custom menu in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

when we create system.xml by default those field are come under store -> configuration.

can we create those fields inside any custom menu using system.xml file?

is this possible?. If possible how can we achieve this or what alternative for this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your menu like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
<tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="50">
<label>vendor</label>
</tab>
<section id="vendor" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<class>separator-top</class>
<label>Adding custom entries</label>
<tab>vendor</tab>
<resource>Vendor_Extension::config_extension</resource>
<group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>General Configuration</label>
<field id="vendor_dropdown_custom" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>Vendor Custom Text FIelds</label>
<source_model>Vendor\Extension\Model\Config\Custom</source_model>
</field>
<field id="custom_options" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
<label>Custom Type</label>
<comment>ADD HERE ANY COMMENT IF YOU WANT</comment>
</field>
</group>
</section>
</system>
</config>
```